OpenGL error 1281 when trying to assign a texture to an object
I was trying to texturize my square, at first it worked perfectly, but then I tried to put all the texture loading and creating and all that stuff in a function, but then, it stopped working. I reverted back to the messy spaghetti code but it didn't work either.
Here is main.c:
#include "pijote.h"
#include "pichacorta.h"
static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if ((key==GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE&&action==GLFW_PRESS)||(key==GLFW_KEY_BACKSPACE&&action==GLFW_PRESS)){
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    }
}

static void onResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
static void Checkforglerrors() {
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\nopengl error: %d", error);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {
    if (!glfwInit()){
        printf("\nglfw init failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(CM_GLFW_WIN_WIDTH, CM_GLFW_WIN_HEIGHT, CM_WIN_NAME , NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        printf("\nglfw win creation failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -2;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGL()){
        printf("\nglad init failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -3;
    }
    int nrAttributes;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &nrAttributes);
    printf("\nmaximum number of vertex attributes supported: %i", nrAttributes);
    int FBwidth, FBheight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &FBwidth, &FBheight);
    glViewport(0, 0, FBwidth, FBheight);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, onResizeCallback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);


    Shader* mepicaelculo = 0;
    const char* vertexshaderpath = "vertshaderf.file";
    const char* fragmentshaderpath = "fragshaderf.file";
    Shader_create(&mepicaelculo, vertexshaderpath, fragmentshaderpath);

    float vertices[] = {
        0.5,0.5,0.0,        1.0,0.0,0.0,        1.0,1.0,
        0.5,-0.5,0.0,       0.0,1.0,0.0,        1.0,0.0,
        -0.5,-0.5,0.0,  0.0,0.0,1.0,        0.0,0.0,
        -0.5,0.5,0.0,       1.0,1.0,0.0,        0.0,1.0
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0,1,3,
        1,2,3
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    
    unsigned int puton;
    
    glGenTextures(1, &puton);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, puton);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    /*GLint Boundtexture;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &Boundtexture);
    printf("\ncurrently bound texture %d",Boundtexture);*/
    int width, height, nChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("puton but much better.png", &width, &height, &nChannels, 0);
    if (data){
        /*for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); ++i) {
            printf("\nPixel %d: %d %d %d", i, data[i * nChannels], data[i * nChannels + 1], data[i * nChannels + 2]);
        }*/
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }else{
        printf("texture loading failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -15;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    /*unsigned int PIJOTE
    glGenTextures(1, &PIJOTE);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, PIJOTE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    data = stbi_load("PICHA.png", &width, &height, &nChannels, 0);

    if (data){
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }else{
        printf("texture loading failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -15;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);*/

    Shader_use(mepicaelculo);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mepicaelculo, "texture1"), 0);
    //glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mepicaelculo, "texture2"), 1);
    Checkforglerrors(); //THE ERROR CODE IS GIVEN HERE 
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        
        /*glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, PIJOTE);*/
        Shader_use(mepicaelculo);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, puton);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    printf("\ntesticulos\n");
    return 1;
}

Here is pijote.h:
#pragma once
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <glad.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <BaseTsd.h>
#include "stb_image.h"
//width of the window created by glfw
#define CM_GLFW_WIN_WIDTH 640
//height of the window created by glfw
#define CM_GLFW_WIN_HEIGHT 480
//window name
#define CM_WIN_NAME "Project 3D"

here is pichacorta.h:
#pragma once
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H
#include "pijote.h"

typedef struct {
    unsigned int ID;
}Shader;

void Shader_create(Shader* shaderID, const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath);
void Shader_use(Shader * shaderID);
void Shader_setBool(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, bool value);
void Shader_setInt(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, int value);
void Shader_setFloat(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, float value);

void checkCompileErrorShader(unsigned int shader, const char* type);
void checkCompileErrorProgram(unsigned int shader);

#endif

And here is pichacorta.c:
#include "pichacorta.h"

void checkCompileErrorShader(unsigned int shader, const char* type) {
    int success;
    char infolog[1024];
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infolog);
        printf("\n%s shader compilation failed: %s", type, infolog);
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-11);
    }
}
void checkCompileErrorProgram(unsigned int shader) {
    int success;
    char infolog[1024];
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infolog);
        printf("\nprogram linking failed: %s", infolog);
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-12);
    }
}

void Shader_create(Shader* shaderID, const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath){
    char* vertexCode = "a";
    char* fragmentCode = "a";
    int filesize1;
    int filesize2;
    FILE* vertFile= fopen(vertexPath, "r+");
    if (vertFile == NULL) {
        printf("\nvertex file opening failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-7);
    }
    FILE* fragFile = fopen(fragmentPath, "r");
    if (fragFile == NULL) {
        printf("\nfragment file opening failed");
        fclose(vertFile);
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-8);
    }
    //I HATE comments 
    //this code (↓↓) is just for writing the contents on the vertex file to the variable "vertexCode"
    fseek(vertFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize1 = ftell(vertFile);
    rewind(vertFile);
    vertexCode = (char*)malloc(filesize1);
    char *curchar= (char*)malloc(filesize1);
    vertexCode[0] = 0;
    for (int pijote=1; fgets(curchar, filesize1, vertFile); ) {
        strcat(vertexCode, curchar);
        pijote++;
    }
    fclose(vertFile);
    free(curchar);
    //I HATE comments
    //this code (↓↓) is just for writing the contents on the fragment file to the variable "fragmentCode"
    fseek(fragFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize2 = ftell(fragFile);
    rewind(fragFile);
    fragmentCode = (char*)malloc(filesize2);
    char* curchar2 = (char*)malloc(filesize2);
    if (fragmentCode){
        fragmentCode[0] = 0;
        for (int pijote = 1; fgets(curchar2, filesize2, fragFile); ) {
            if (curchar2){
                strcat(fragmentCode, curchar2);
            }else{
                perror("curchar is null (idk what thats supposed to mean)");
                exit(-17);
            }
            
            pijote++;
        }
        fclose(fragFile);
        free(curchar2);
    }else{
        perror("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(-16);
    }
    
    //I know, it's not the best way to do it, but hey, if it works don't touch it 
    const char* constvertcode = vertexCode;
    const char* constfragcode = fragmentCode;


    unsigned int vertex,  fragment;
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &constvertcode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    checkCompileErrorShader(vertex, "vertex");

    fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &constfragcode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    checkCompileErrorShader(fragment, "fragment");

    shaderID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderID, vertex);
    glAttachShader(shaderID, fragment);
    glLinkProgram(shaderID);
    checkCompileErrorProgram(shaderID);
    
    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);
}
void Shader_use(Shader* shaderID) {
    glUseProgram(shaderID);
}

void Shader_setBool(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, bool value) {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, name), (int)value);
}

void Shader_setInt(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, int value) {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, name), value);
}

void Shader_setFloat(unsigned int shaderID, const char* name, float value) {
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, name), value);
}

The only thing that gave me a hint of what was happening was the GL error 1281.  There was a result for stack overflow, of someone with the same error but he was getting the error because of some error checking he was doing. I believe I'm getting the error upon setting the uniform.

Unrelated: very good resaon to start working with some version control system so that this doesn't happen again the future.

Which gl* call actually generates the error?

That's closer to a [mcve]!  Still need to merge all those headers/source-files into a single file and edit in the fragment/vertex shader source files.  Also, how did you get this to compile?  glAttachShader() takes a GLuint as its first argument, not a Shader*.
